# Can gnome network manager automatically find certificate to install for WPA2 enterprise wifi?

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager

I am attempting to connect to the EDUROAM network at my university using fedora 27 but I can't get it configured right. I tried on macOS and when I entered my username and password I was asked if I wanted to install the certificate for this network but on Fedora I ticked no certificate needed.

How would I get this certificate on fedora and can I get network manager to set up the right configuration automatically like MacOS did?

Comment: Please define better "installing" certificate in macOS (hint: normally, it does not install it just by accessing EDUROAM via wifi). Have you tried your local heldesk already?

Comment: Forget the network and try again.